# Crystal Report suppressing columns according to days

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, suppression

I have created a report which is basically a pivot table (days as columns), so the must report shows the columns according to the respective month i.e 28 columns will be for February.

I have tried it with the parameters, but got no result. Can anyone help?

this is the code

if {?sDtRange2}=DateValue(2)
then true
else false

Comment: what do you want to supress here? using the number of days in month. your question is not clear

Comment: It's **column** - not *coloumn*

Comment: i want to suppress columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made three formulae feilds naming
Day29, Day30, and Day31 and placed them in header section ,whereas their detail feilds are placed in details section which are database feilds.

**formulae used for day 29 is**

datetimevar z:= DateTimeValue ({?My Parameter});
numberVar y:= year(z) mod 4;

if y=0 and month(z)=2 then
    "29"
else
if y<>0 and month(z)=2 then
    ""
else
if month(z)<>2 then
    "29"

**formulae used for day 30 is**

datetimevar z:=DateTimeValue({?My Parameter});

if month(z)<>2 then
    "30"
else
    ""
**formulae used for day 31 is**
datetimevar z:= DatetimeValue ({?My Parameter});

if (month(z)=1 or month(z)=3 or month(z)=5 or month(z)=7 or month(z)=8 or month(z)=10 or month(z)=12) then
    "31"
else
    ""
and respectively 
put this formulae in their database feilds.

**For Day 29 db feild in report in details section**

if {@Day 29}= "29"
then true
else false

**For Day 30 db feild in report in details section**

if {@Day 30}= "30"
then true
else false

**For Day 31 db feild in report in details section**

if {@Day 31}= "31"
then true
else false

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use crosstab for this purpose that will populate all days column wise.

```
1. In crosstab, go to `crosstab expert`
2. In column part give month first and then date field from database as second column so that your month dates are grouped together.
3. In summary give the field you want to summarize
```

This soltuion works as per your question description.. if this is not your issue try to explain more briefly as you didn't mention what all columns you want to supress and basing on what `condition`.